# ReactJs - Unit Testing Using Mocha , Upgrading to Babel 7 from Babel 6

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

Did an upgrade from Babel v6 - v7 @latest today, And for some of the existing unit tests using Mocha and Enzyme (pretty standard) started crashing.
Getting this error in the console

```
\node_modules\reselect\lib\index.js:53
    throw new Error('Selector creators expect all input-selectors to be functions, ' + ('instead received the following types: [' + dependencyTypes + ']'));
```

Further digging into the pattern of tests which are failing - Could spot that the test where have referenced i.e imported component from an index lookup is failing, If provide actual path it starts working fine.

By Index look mean below - All our components are categorized and then imported/exported. We have been using this pattern from 3 years now

```
import ABC from './common/Folder/ABC';
.
.
.
import XYZ from './common/Folder/XYZ';

export {
ABC,
.
.
XYZ
}
```

The error happens when in Unit Test file we import like below

```
1.import { ABC } from 'componentIndex';
```

If direct path is provided starts working

```
2. import { ABC } from '../../ABC';
```

Please let me know if for any questions you might have in this context.

Any suggestion what I might be missing that is causing this error. Any babel plugin ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in the

1.import { ABC } from 'componentIndex';

When ABC was imported , seems like babel checked componentIndex for its correctness and in there was a reference to a files which had createSelector from reselect. While the unit test was executed, some of the selectors couldn't resolve and resulted in error.

Added console log in the selectors and ran only the subsets of tests related to selectors and fixed those to support TDD. Once selectors were unit testable, Ran the whole suites and didn't face the error earlier.

Not sure how they were working on version 6.